# Can I use the same SSL cert for HTTPS and FTPS

Tags: https, subdomain

I am looking to get an extended SSL certificate for a server that is handling one of my subdomains. Can I use the same certificate for `https://sub.example.com` and `ftps://sub.example.com`, assuming that that they both resolve to the same ip on the same box?

Windows 2008 R2

Apache 2.2.12 w/ OpenSSL/1.0.0e

FileZilla Server 0.9.39 beta

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An SSL certificate does not specify an IP, a protocol or a server.

SSL cerificates are, however, tied to a specific (sub)domain.

So yes, you **can** use the same certificate for both, even if you decide to host website and FTP server on two different locations.

Some certificates even allow you to change the subdomain (so called wildcard certificates), but they're too expensive for most purposes.

Comment: And as a side note: EV certificates do not allow wildcards.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, SSL certificates are not tied to a specific TCP port, so this shouldn't be a problem. Only the CN of the certificate has to match the DNS host name of your server.

Comment: Actually, it's primarily the Subject Alternative Name (SAN), the CN should only be a fallback solution (see RFC 6125).